# Emoji keyboard suddenly changed?

Tags: keyboard, font, emoji

All of the sudden, I am not getting the nice and quick emoji keyboard (see [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uUdR.jpg)) popup, but instead a big window of all type faces, which is not gaining focus for easy emoji insertion without moving my hands from the keyboard ([2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxvLt.png)).

How do I get the old one back?

[image: Old emoji keyboard]

[image: New emoji keyboard]

Comment: See https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201586

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click on the top right icon to get the previous keyboard

[image]

Comment: ‍♀️ (typed with ease)